# C# Editing Read-Only variable internally

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a variable that I can modify only from within the class but is readable from outside the class.

```
public int id { get; } //And set but only internal
```

Comment: `private/protected set;` doesn't works as you want?

Comment: The reason you've gotten all the down votes is two fold. 1) This is a basic question that could be readily answered with a little research. 2) the site seems to have downvote rovers who look for questions to push down.

Comment: @Displayname I would go with 1) ^^ .. This is just very very basic `c#` and shows that the according [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/restricting-accessor-accessibility) wasn't even considered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add qualifiers to the get and set accessors separately.

```
public int id { get; private set; }
```

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/restricting-accessor-accessibility

Comment: don't just chuck badly formatted code at OP - add some _explanation_ at least what it does and why it does it.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann better?

Comment: Why the question has 3 downvotes? i didn't found something similar...